# Prove sequence defined by recurrence relation using induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction, recurrence-relations

[image]

Confused at this question, from what I gather strong induction is necessary here to prove this but the algebraic step after the Inductive Hypothesis is where I'm not too sure.

**Basis:**
2 <= a<sub>1</sub> = 2 <= 4
2 <= a<sub>2</sub> = 2 <= 4

**Inductive Hypothesis:**
Assume that for any 2 < n <= k, we have that 2 <= a<sub>n</sub> <= 4

Show a<sub>n+1</sub> is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base case is correct.

Now, fix an $n\geq 3$ and suppose that for all $k<n$, $2\leq a_{k}\leq 4$. We want to show that $2\leq a_{n}\leq 4$. Note that
$$
a_{n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n-1}+\frac{8}{a_{n-2}}\right)\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(4+\frac{8}{2}\right)=4
$$

and

$$
a_{n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n-1}+\frac{8}{a_{n-2}}\right)\geq \frac{1}{2}\left(2+\frac{8}{4}\right)=2,
$$
by  the inductive hypothesis.

Hence, $2\leq a_{n}\leq 4$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks so much! Prepping for an exam and while I think I understand induction, some of these recurrence relation questions trip me up sometimes.